# How to combine two different deep learning models which have been trained on different datasets?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, ensemble-learning

I have two deep learning models. One is trained using YOLOv5s and the other one was trained using YOLOv4.Both of them were trained on different datasets and their classes are different from each other. I have the final weight files for both of them. I want to combine these models so as to run the detections in a single live video feed. i.e detections for all the classes from models 1 and 2 in a single video feed. I want to ask whether it is possible to do so?

Comment: I think you just have to run both the models and merge the resulting bounding boxes.

Comment: @marcoromelli Wont it slow down my detections?

Comment: Compared to using only one model, yes. Doesn't mean it will be too slow for your application; you have to try yourself. If it's too slow you have to train a single model on both datasets merged in a single one.

Comment: >"Wont it slow down my detections?"
 Yes, but you can: (1) run both models in different threads (2) use a fast framework for inference (TensorRT, OpenVINO) (3) once convert frame to input tensor for both networks

Comment: @Nuzhny Can you please elaborate your 3rd point? Hw can I do that?

Comment: You can make one call  im = torch.from_numpy(im).to(device) and after  pred1 = model1(im) and pred2 = model2(im)